# Spring no working correctly in Intellij idea

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am trying to work on a new IDE, Spring was working fine, I was able to run Tomcat and I could load pages on local servers.
But, I added several dependencies in the XML and now it does not run tomcat.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NnEx.png

POM.XML --> Dependencies used

Java-version

```
<properties>
<java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
```

Spring MVC:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Tomcat Embed:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

JSTL:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

To compile JSP files

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Test:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

SPRING DATA:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

MySQL:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<scope>runtime</scope>
<version>5.1.47</version>
</dependency>
```

Commons-lang3:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
<version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

tika-parsers

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
<artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
<version>1.17</version>
</dependency>
```

File upload

```
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
<version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try with any of the below two approaches:**

**Approach 1:**

You can try it by **removing the below dependency** from pom.xml as `tomcat-embed-jasper` includes dependency with `tomcat-embed-core`.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Approach 2:**

**Remove** the `scope` as `provided` from `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency as shown below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**Note:** *I was able to **replicate this issue** and it worked fine for me with the above approaches.*

Comment: Thanks my friend, I spent hours looking for a solution!
Thank you very much !

Comment: @AngelloG_Delatorre Glad that it resolved your problem!